# Ajax call does not work second time. controller action is not hitting second time

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

I'm facing some weird issue, my ajax call to controller action isn't calling second time. first time it gets called and breakpoint is getting hit. but second time it's not even view displayed with previous values.

I'm using jqgrid.ondblClickRow and I need to open a view as dilaog.

jgqGrid code is here...

```
            ondblClickRow: function () {
                                     
                    getUserProfile();
                },
```

and getUserProfile function is as below

```
           function getUserProfile() {                
            
            var rowId = $("#userGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            if (rowId == null) {
                clearUserDetailSection();
                return;
            }
            var rowData = jQuery("#userGrid").getRowData(rowId);
            userId = $(rowData.Userid)[0].innerText;
            
            $("#ProfilePopUp").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 500,
                width: 1000,
                modal: true
            });
            LoadRolesData(userId, RolesForUserUrl);                
            $('#ProfilePopUp').dialog('open');
            return;
        }
```

here is the code for LoadRoleData function.

````
    ```
    function LoadRolesData(userId, getRolesForUserUrl) {
     $("#RolesTable").jqGrid
    ({
        url: getRolesForUserUrl,
        postData: { userId: userId },
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'Post',
        colNames: ['Division', 'Roles'],
        colModel: [
            {
                name: "DivisionNumber", width: 200, sortable: true, sorttype: "number", search: true, number: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'] }, align: "center",
                formatter: function () { return FormatGridCells("Barnes&Noble"); }
            },
            {
                name: "RoleDesc", width: 350, sortable: true, sorttype: "text", search: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn', 'nc', 'nu', 'nn'] },
                formatter: function (cellvalue) { return FormatGridCells(cellvalue); }
            }

        ],
        jsonReader:
        {
            root: "rows",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false
        },
        rowNum: -1,
        height: '100',
        viewrecords: true,
        emptyrecords: 'No records',
        toppager: false,
        sortable: false,
        loadComplete: function () {
            $("tr.jqgrow:odd").css("background", "#CCCCCC");
        }
    }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#RolesTable_toppager', { search: false, edit: false, add: false, del: false });
````

}

```
Can someone have any Idea, I need to use ondblClickRow event only. Help appreciated.
```